# Execute ssh shell script from npm command

Tags: bash, npm, osascript, shelljs

I'm trying to write an npm script that will execute an ssh shell command. Currently it's working by executing an `osascript` command to open a Terminal window and run the command.

I'd like to change this to execute the command in the current terminal. The script is including both `shelljs` and `executive`. The script ends without anything happening when I use `executive`. With `shelljs` I get:

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
the input device is not a TTY`

The command being executed is: `ssh -i [ssh-key] -t ubuntu@[ip-address] eval $(base64 -D <<< [command in base64])`

The base64 command is `sudo docker exec -i -t $(sudo docker ps -aqf "ancestor=' + containerName + '") /bin/bash`

If I output the command and copy and paste it, it will work as expected, sshing into a remote machine and running a `docker exec` command.

If I remove the `-t` option I don't get the warning messages but there's no output in the console and the script hangs (I assume it's running the command in the background with no output). If I remove the `eval ...` part I get an output that looks like what you'd see when sshing into a server but without the input terminal.

What can I do to execute this command in the same terminal or in a new tab. If I have to use an `osascript` command to do this, that's fine as well. I'll be executing this command from the terminal in PhpStorm though.

**Edit**

Here's the block of code:

```
var execCommand = 'sudo docker exec -i -t $(sudo docker ps -aqf "ancestor=nginx") /bin/bash';

var buffer = new Buffer(execCommand);
var encoded = buffer.toString('base64');

var cmd = "ssh -i " + this.keyPath + " -t ubuntu@" + ip + " eval $(base64 -D <<< " + encoded + ") ";

shell.exec(cmd);
```

**Edit 2**

I can ssh into the machine successfully and get a command prompt but I'm getting a `the input device is not a TTY` error now when I add the `eval` command.

```
var docker_exec = 'sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps -aqf "ancestor=' + containerName + '") /bin/bash';
var encoded = new Buffer(docker_exec).toString('base64');

var sshTerm = spawn('ssh', [
    '-i',
    this.keyPath,
    'ubuntu@' + ip,
    'eval',
    'eval $(base64 -D <<< ' + encoded + ')'
], {
    stdio: 'inherit',
    shell: true
});

sshTerm.on('exit', function() {
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have used?

Comment: @TarunLalwani hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and it shelljs.exec is good for non TTY commands. For TTY based command you can use normal spawn method. Below is a sample code that works great for me

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var sshTerm = spawn('ssh', ["vagrant@192.168.33.100", ""], {
  stdio: 'inherit'
});

// listen for the 'exit' event
//   which fires when the process exits
sshTerm.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
  if (code === 0) {
    // process completed successfully
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll test this later today and get back to you!

Comment: That was a big help but I'm getting another error. Can you check out my edit 2 and see what you think?

Comment: Try adding `'-tt',` before `'ubuntu@' + ip,`